# numpy datetime64 from day, month, year series

Tags: python, numpy

I have dates are three numpy arrays containing each all the days, months or years separately.

From these date-components I would like to construct a numpy.datetime64 array:

```
date = np.datetime64(days, months, years)
```

Of course the above does not work. The numpy documentation is silent on how to parse dates from anything other than strings.

I am sure somebody has already solved this riddle before...

Comment: @eumiro Many thanks for the link to the duplicate question. The procedure is oddly complicated...

Answer (score 0):

First Convert to date time like

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime(year, month, date)
```

then

```
date = np.datetime64(dt)
```

Comment: I think a question is more about batch, rather than converting single date

Comment: yes, you are right, Should i delete it?

Comment: Thanks. I have indeed a multiple arrays with the date components. - But never mind. My question turned out to have been a duplicate.